# Get client-side port number in Symfony for request sent via SSH local port forwarding

Tags: php, symfony, portforwarding

This might not be specific to Symfony since the client-side port number is not visible in the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

Occasionally, I use SSH local port forwarding to preview an AWS ElasticBeanstalk application that lives in the private subnet (not accessible from the internet).

```
 $ ssh -L 8088:helloworld.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:80 bastion
```

Where the `bastion` host is in the public subnet, and can make HTTP requests to servers in the private subnet.

When I run this command, I can visit the site at `http://localhost:8088/`

This works well, unless a part of the site requires the port number - at least in Symfony anyway. When part of the site raises a 403 Forbidden response because authentication is required, Symfony will perform a redirect to a login page, using `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils::createRedirectResponse()`.

It tries to redirect to a URL using `$requst->getSchemeAndHttpHost()` as the base. However, this removes the port number as it has determined the port to be `80` instead of `8088`.

Inspecting the `$_SERVER` value in Xdebug reveals:

`HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT = 80
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = 10.0.0.48
HTTP_HOST = localhost
SERVER_PORT = 80
SERVER_ADDR = 10.0.2.70
REMOTE_PORT = 44348
REMOTE_ADDR = 10.0.3.215`

The port number `8088` in the original request is not visible anywhere.

Comment: The SSH tunnel is a lower level of connection to the HTTP protocol so it will not add or modify any HTTP headers. You can probably have better results by setting up a local web server as a reverse proxy.

Comment: @apokryfos would this local reverse proxy sit in front of the tunnel ?

Comment: Using a tunnel will not work. You need to get the reverse proxy to work without a tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way Symfony (actually Webserver) can get your local address, there are 2 possible ways to solve the issue:

1. Make the private network accessible through a reverse proxy on the public one.
2. Setup reverse proxy on your work machine (like nginx) so that it will accept requests for `workproject.local` domain, add headers like `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Real-Ip` to incoming requests and pass these requests through the tunnel.

In any way you also have to configure symfony to work under a reverse proxy, for more information read the official docs:
[How to Configure Symfony to Work behind a Load Balancer or a Reverse Proxy](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html)